# I want to write a code to automate excel chart on Python.Problem is that need to use templates

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Here's my problem : I found some code that creates charts, but I need to use some specific templates for my chart, for example Stacked5 or Staked2 and so on. Is it possible?

I have tried to write char type howe it stays by templates Stacked2,

```
import random
import pandas as pd

# Some sample data to plot.
cat_4 = ['Metric_' + str(x) for x in range(1, 9)]
index_4 = ['Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data 3', 'Data 4']
data_3 = {}
for cat in cat_4:
    data_3[cat] = [random.randint(10, 100) for x in index_4]

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame(data_3, index=index_4)

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
excel_file = 'stacked_column.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'Stacked'})

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
for col_num in range(1, len(cat_4) + 1):
    print(col_num)
    chart.add_series({
            'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, col_num],
            'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 1, 4, 1],
            'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, col_num, 4, col_num],
            'gap':        2,
    })

# Configure the chart axes.
chart.set_y_axis({'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('K2', chart)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

[My source](https://pandas-xlsxwriter-charts.readthedocs.io/chart_stacked_column.html)

There was no error by running code, but when I try to open excel file I get message:

```
we found a problem, with some content in 'stacked_column.xlsx'. Do you want to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes.
```

By clicking yes I get: Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content, if I click view I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>Repair Result to stacked_column1.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file ’/Users/my_name/Desktop/Chart_scpt/stacked_column.xlsx’</summary><removedParts summary="Following is a list of removed parts:"><removedPart>Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)</removedPart></removedParts></recoveryLog>
```

The Excel doc has no chart at all.